# How to connect php-fpm with nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, fpm

I have a server that uses Nginx and PHP-FPM. It was working as well, I executed the following command for some reasons:

```
apt-get --purge remove php-common
```

After that, I executed this:

```
apt-get install php-common php-mysql php-cli
```

Commands executed successfully, but I get 502 error when I want to access websites on the servers:

[image]

It should be noted, there are several projects on this server. And I have nothing inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available`. I have all configurations under `/etc/nginx/conf.d`. See:

[image]

Each of them is a project. Now, I guess I need to set to PHP-FPM to use `conf.d` instead of `sites-available`. Any idea how can I do that?

Could you please help me how can I debug it?

Comment: Read server logs

Comment: @Justinas You mean `tail -f /var/log/nginx/`? If yes, this is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqu0C.png

Comment: So than go ahead and fix it